# Nginx config for Magento subfolder multistore

Tags: nginx, rewrite, magento

I'm moving from subdomain to subfolder.

I have multiple subfolders for several countries. I changed the domain in the Magento administration. But the Nginx rewrite doesn't seem to work. I have 1 Magento installation on my server and want to use /uk and /us.

The page is loading but all pages are giving me a 404 error.

I've been spending many hours on Google but can't find a working configuration. Hope someone can give a clue.

This is my config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;   
root /home/domain_com/public_html/;
server_name www.domain.com/uk;
if ($http_host = cache.domain.com) {
rewrite  (.*)  https://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}
if ($http_host = uk.domain.com) {
rewrite  (.*)  https://www.domain.com/uk$1 permanent;
}
location / {
index index.html index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
expires 30d;
}
location /downloader/ {
allow xx.xx.xx.xx;
deny all;
}
location ~ ^/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }
location /var/export/ { internal; }
location /. { return 404; }
location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
location ~* .php/ { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
location ~* .php$ {
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
expires off;
fastcgi_pass domain;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE ic_uk;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration has lots of problems. I don't know where you found it, but I would advise you not to go there again.

First:

```
location /. { return 404; }
```

It will match everything but the home page. It's not clear why you have this to begin with.

Second:

```
server_name www.domain.com/uk;
```

This is obviously not valid, as `/` cannot appear in host names. Change this to [something appropriate](http://nginx.org/r/server_name).

Third:

```
location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }
```

You send everything here which isn't a static resource from your `try_files`, but the rewrite only matches the URL path `/`. So again, you should expect to get 404s from everything except the home page. This can be trivially fixed by changing it to `^`, which will match everything.

It's also not clear why you don't just pass directly to FastCGI from this `location`. The rest of them are redundant.

---

Those are just the obvious problems I see which will prevent the config from working at all. There are still plenty of other bad practices in here (such as improper use of `if`) which you should also clean up later.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts! Can you help me with the 3th problem? When I change it to location @handler { rewrite / ^index.php; } I get 'No input file specified'

Comment: But you changed the wrong `/`!

Comment: It solves the  'No input file specified' error but all pages are still giving me 404's. Now I have `location @handler { rewrite ^ /index.php; }`

Comment: Well this is getting to be a mess! Maybe you should just throw out this configuration and start over.

Comment: Do you have a good resource for Nginx configs? The funny thing is that this config is working for my subdomains (us.domain.com).

Comment: @IlQuadrifoglio I found your nginx config on the Magento wiki. I'm quite surprised it's there, considering how bad it is. A much better set of nginx configs can be found at https://github.com/magenx/Magento-nginx-config

Comment: I tried that one also. But still only 404's...